# VSFTP authentication with client certificate

Tags: centos, authentication, ssl-certificate, ftp

I have a VPS Box running on CentOS 6.5 with vsftpd.

I have setup a user account for login with username/password.

My customer now sent me a id_rsa_2048.pub key which he wants to use for authentication instead of username/password combination for his username let's say "testaccount".

What do i have to change in my vsftpd config to authenticate against his certificate?

Comment: This sounds like a possible miscommunication. It appears your client wants to use SSH File Transfer Protocol with public key authentication, which is a complete different protocol from regular (or SSL secured) FTP for which you would use vsftpd. http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSH_File_Transfer_Protocol

Comment: he wrote SFTP in his mail

Comment: In CentOS sftp is supported by the OpenSSH server in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` a recipe is here https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/SFTP_chroot